# Executing a python line of code using eval() from a map

Tags: python, eval

Let's say that I have a line of code that is a string:

```
a="print 'x + y = ', x + y"
```

Now I want to execute it using eval()

So if I have already given x & y values beforhand, I know that can write:

```
eval (compile (a,"test.py", "single"))
```

And it will work great.

But I want to give them values from a dict.  In other words, if I have a dict:

```
b={'x':4,'y':3}
```

I want the values that will go into x & y to come from b.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you checked the [documentation for `eval()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval)? There's a couple more parameters you can use for exactly this purpose. For example:

```
>>> b = {'x':4,'y':3}
>>> eval("x + y", b)
7
```

Comment: Thanx for the reply..
should there be a difference when the code you execute is 
"print 'x + y = ', x + y" or "x+y"?
since the first dosen't work with what you offerd..

Comment: When you're running a statement like `print`, then you just need to put the pieces together. For example, `eval(compile("print x + y", "<string>", "single"), b)`

Answer (score 0):

For statements, you should use `exec`:

in Python 2.x:

```
exec "print 'x + y = ', x + y" in {'x':4,'y':3}
```

in Python 3.x:

```
exec("print('x + y = ', x + y)", {'x':4,'y':3})
```

(of course, `print` is not a statement in Python 3, so there is no need in this case)